# Flutter equivalent to Timber + Crashlytics?

Tags: logging, flutter, crashlytics, timber-android

Are there any Timber + Crashlytics for Flutter? I am looking for a solution where I can easily log my app's behavior and filter the log priority to be printed (debug, info, error and etc.) and also have it automatically uploaded to Crashlytics, as we can do this easily in Android with Timber integrated with Crashlytics.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the same thing. There is Fimber, which is in essence Timber for Flutter. My thought was to extend Fimber and have the extension do the work of either calling Crashlytics for production, or just use Fimber to log locally. This shouldn't be too hard to accomplish BUT if you look at the TODO Roadmap here, https://pub.dev/packages/fimber, it looks like they have a plan to do just this. Hopefully it is soon.

Comment: I searched for many logging options for Flutter and pure Dart. At the end I just found them all complicated and decided to just use crashlytics as the logging framework.